# How can i solve the double scrollbar problem?

Tags: double, scrollbar

I just added the footer to my page and noticed that there are two scrollbars on the page. I tried to remove the footer, but nothing.
My site: https://vilagtitkok.hu/

I tried to enter in css that overflow-y: hidden and one of the scrollbars disappeared, but I could not scroll on the page. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the live site I can only see 1 scrollbar. 